# fb:login-button doesnt work without show-faces

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

We just switched to new PHP SDK and JS today. but the problem is weird. When we dont use show-faces with perms attribute it doesnt show popup. Only way to get permission popup appear, we need to use show-faces attr.

is this a bug ?

```
<fb:login-button perms="email, publish_stream, offline_access, create_event, user_photos, user_online_presence, user_videos, user_website, user_events, user_relationships, user_interests" size="large">Sign Up With Facebook</fb:login-button>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId: '<?php echo $facebook->getAppID() ?>',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
```

Thanks

EDIT:

OMG. i just found the solution, with the new JS SDK we must use scope instead of perms attribute!

Comment: Out of curiosity, try fewer permissions and see what would happen..like: `perms="read_stream"`

Comment: tried that, i used only 1 permission but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the new JS SDK we must use scope instead of perms attribute!

Comment: Correct. If the oauth parameter in FB.init is set to true, then you must use the scope parameter instead of perms.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use straight Javascript and make your own buttons.

```
<script>
    function addPermissions(permissions){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {
                    // user is logged in and granted some permissions.

                } else {
                    // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions

                }
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
            }
        }, {perms:permissions});
    }
</script>
<a onclick="addPermissions("email, publish_stream,...");">Click me</a>
```

Comment: He is not asking for an alternative solution :)

Comment: yeah i know this alternative but i dont want to use like that, thx tho

Comment: Guess I've been burned too much by XFBML to even go near it.  Javascript tends to be more reliable in the cases I've worked with.